# Dados do MySQL não são inseridos

Tags: java, mysql, conexão

Olá, estou tentando inserir dados no mysql pelo netbeans, mas sempre retorna o erro "null". Quando dou refresh no mysql a tabela continua sem os dados inseridos. Não tem erro na sintaxe, ele apenas não insere os dados e retorna o erro null. O mesmo acontece para qualquer outro comando de manipulação de dados.

```
public class ClienteDAO {


private Connection conexao = null;
private Statement declaracao = null;
private ResultSet resultado = null;


public void addCliente(Cliente cli){

    String script = "INSERT INTO cliente (Nome, Idade, Endereco) VALUES(?, ?, ?);";
    try {
        PreparedStatement stmt = conexao.prepareStatement(script);

        stmt.setString(1, cli.getNome());
        stmt.setInt(2, cli.getIdade());
        stmt.setString(3, cli.getLocal());
        System.out.println(script); //coloquei esse sout para verificar a sintaxe e quando executo o programa ele não é exibido
        stmt.executeUpdate();


    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("ERROR - Inserir dados: "+e.getMessage());
    }


}
public void listarClientes(){
    String query = "select * from cliente;";

    try {
        PreparedStatement declaracao = conexao.prepareStatement(query);
        resultado = declaracao.executeQuery();

        while (resultado.next()) {
            System.out.println("Codigo: "+resultado.getInt("Codigo")+"\nNome: "+resultado.getString("Nome")+
                    "\nIdade: "+resultado.getInt("Idade")+"Endereço: "+resultado.getString("Endereco"));
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("ERROR MYSQL: "+e.getMessage());
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Falta fechar a conexão, ou comitar manualmente a transação

Comment: Ainda ta dando null, talvez seja pq eu atualizei o jdk

Comment: poste a stacktrace completa, mas pelo que vejo você não chegou nem a pegar a conexão com o banco. `conexao` deve ser nula sempre

Comment: Coloca um SqlException no lugar do Exception para ter um erro mais especifico.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver o problema. Realmente as minhas variáveis estavam ficando nulas, depurei linha por linha pra descobrir isso. então declarei todas as variáveis de conexão e manipulação do banco de dados no meu método Conexão (que é um objeto estático) e chamei na minha classe ClienteDAO.

obs:não chamo a conexão no método pq faço isso no main.

public class ClienteDAO {

```
public void addCliente(Cliente cli){

    String script = "INSERT INTO cliente (Nome, Idade, Endereco, Senha) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?);";
    try {
        Conexao.pstmt = Conexao.conexao.prepareStatement(script);

        Conexao.pstmt.setString(1, cli.getNome());
        Conexao.pstmt.setInt(2, cli.getIdade());
        Conexao.pstmt.setString(3, cli.getLocal());
        Conexao.pstmt.setString(4, cli.getSenha());
        Conexao.pstmt.executeUpdate();


    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "ERROR - Inserir dados: "+e.getMessage());
    }


}
```